# Create a Web Invoice Via Mobile App

Tags: paypal

Im creating the iOS counterpart for an app that allows charitable donations. Google allows this, but as per Apple's terms this must be done via an external weblink.

Does paypal have an API to create a donation inside of the app and then launch safari with an auto generated invoice for that donation?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a donate button specific to the Apple IOS. 
Here is the information from the Mobile Payments Library Guide. 
You will want to add the sub-button type of invoice. SUBTYPE_INVOICE
Page 24 and Page 25 of the MPL IOS Library has the details.

> **PayPalInvoiceData** 
>   This object is an optional parameter to a 
>   PayPalPayment
>    or a 
>   PPReceiverPaymentDetails
>    object.  This object holds data 
>   regarding the tax shipping and 
>   a per-item breakdown of the items included in the pa
>   yment.  While this is an optional class, once 
>   it is added to a container, it must be 
>   populated with the following required fields.

[PayPal Mobile Payments Library IOS](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_iphone.pdf)
[Mobile Payment Library SDK from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702921/create-a-web-invoice-via-mobile-app)

From Page 10 and 11 of the MPL IOS Guide 
[image]